# Android RecyclerView multiple views class cast exeception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView with three views for two views its working fine but when I am adding third view at the end it is giving me class cast exception.

I think I am missing something in recyclerview because if I use my third view at second position in that it is working. Please let me know what I am missing.

**My adapter:**

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View itemLayoutView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(getItemViewType(i)==0){

        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.first, null);
        viewHolder = new EnterHolder(itemLayoutView);
    } else if (getItemViewType(i)==1){
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.last, null);
        viewHolder = new LastHolder(itemLayoutView);
    }
    else {
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.image, null);
        viewHolder = new ImageHolder(itemLayoutView);
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position==0) return 0;
        else if(position==9)return 1;
        else return 2;
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    if(getItemViewType(i)==0){
        EnterHolder enterHolder = (EnterHolder) viewHolder;
        enterHolder.title.setText("first");
    } else if(getItemViewType(i)==1){
        LastHolder lastHolder = (LastHolder) viewHolder;
        lastHolder.title.setText("last");
    }
    else {
        ImageHolder imageHolder = (ImageHolder) viewHolder;
        imageHolder.product_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo);
    }

}
```

**Log-cat error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:com.violetstreet.adapter.HorizontalAdapter$ImageHolder cannot be cast to com.violetstreet.adapter.HorizontalAdapter$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this is](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#createViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) the signature of onCreateViewHolder:

```
public final VH createViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
```

so **you passing the `viewType` as parameter to `getItemViewType()`, when you actually believe you are passing the position of the view**.

this is a commom mistake.  change in your code `int i` to `int viewType` and you'll see clearly why your're wrong